# Swift Array closure extension raises an error

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I have an extension on Array instances for looping over with indices in mind like so:

```
extension Array {
    func fun (_ iterator: (Int, Element) -> Void) -> Void {
        for (key,value) in self.enumerated() {
            iterator(key,value)
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I want to call it :

```
[.leading,.trailing,.bottom,.top].fun {
    (index, element) in

    var c : Int = index % 2 == 0 ? 20 : -20 // THAT LINE
    NSLayoutConstraint(item: subView, attribute: element, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: element , multiplier: 1, constant: c ).isActive = true
}
```

However that raises an error: Type of expression is ambiguous without more context.
When I remove the line ("THAT LINE" in the snippet) - it works. When I add this  or any other code, even some variable declarations - it gives me the same exception.

This error appears ONLY in Xcode, in terminal it works:

```
  swift
Welcome to Apple Swift version 3.0.2 (swiftlang-800.0.63 clang-800.0.42.1). Type :help for assistance.
  1>  
  2>  
  3> extension Array { 
  4.     func fun (_ iterator: (Int, Element) -> Void) -> Void { 
  5.         for (key,value) in self.enumerated() { 
  6.             iterator(key,value) 
  7.         } 
  8.     } 
  9. }
 10> [0,1,2,3,4].fun { 
 11.     (index, element) in 
 12.  
 13.     var c : Int = index % 2 == 0 ? 20 : -20 // THAT LINE 
 14.     print(c)
 15. } 
20
-20
20
-20
20
```

Comment: I believe this could be due to a known bug ([SR-1570](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-1570)), Swift can't infer the parameter type of the closure (when calling `fun`) in multi-statement closures without external context. If you explicitly supply the parameter type, your example should compile. When you remove "that line", the supplied closure is no longer a multi-statement closure. Note however that your 2nd example compiles fine for me.

Comment: Thanks dfri, that's what was causing it (full parameter types inferrence)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like type of array elements issue.

Try `[NSLayoutAttribute.leading, NSLayoutAttribute.trailing, NSLayoutAttribute.bottom, NSLayoutAttribute.top]` instead of `[.leading,.trailing,.bottom,.top]`.

And `constant: CGFloat(c)`  instead of `constant: c`.